# Best way of playing a m3u8 stream?

Tags: networking, video, ffmpeg, vlc, streaming

How can one play a `m3u8` stream smoothly and reliably? Here is what I've tried:

`vlc "$link"`

- startup is long
- playback is jittery
- sometimes it doesn't play a valid link

`ffplay "$link"`

- startup is fast
- playback is very jittery and unreliable

Is there some magic `ffplay` options that are optimized for a `m3u8` stream? Should we invoke `ffmpeg` on original stream and pipe it to other apps instead?

Here are some [test streams](https://github.com/iptv-org/iptv):
A FHD stream:
https://chemnitz.iptv-playoutcenter.de/chemnitz/chemnitzfernsehen.stream_1/playlist.m3u8
A very jittery stream:
164.68.124.111/espn2.m3u8

Comment: mpv & audacious play such playlists just fine.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov like mpv "$link" without any switches? Doesn't mpv use ffmpeg under the hood?

Comment: Must work, mpv does use ffmpeg libraries, but not ffmpeg.

Comment: It looks like a bandwidth issue. Your 2nd link plays smooth with ffplay.